# How to get data from selected item in GridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I want to get data from selected item in **GridView**.
My app should work like this: open activity where is *GridView* => *GridView* load data from server (its working) => when I click an item, app get & send data to server.

***Here is Code:***

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            UniqueID = UNIQUEID.getText().toString();
            POints = POINTS.getText().toString();

            DEscription = DESCRIPTION.getText().toString();
            AddPoints = ADDPOINTS.getText().toString();
            //these two strings are displayed on gridview

            Operations(UniqueID, POints, AddPoints, DEscription);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ADDPOINTS = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_points_grid);
            DESCRIPTION = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_points_describtion);

            UniqueID = UNIQUEID.getText().toString();
            POints = POINTS.getText().toString();

            DEscription = DESCRIPTION.getText().toString();
            AddPoints = ADDPOINTS.getText().toString();


            Operations(UniqueID, POints, AddPoints, DEscription);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Inside the `onItemClick()` method,**

Try `parent.getItem(position)`. Or `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`

Hope this was I you were looking for!

Comment: AddPoints = ADDPOINTS.parent.getItem(position); have error, AddPoints = ADDPOINTS.parent.getItem(position).toStrinng(); same